# System.identityHashCode() giving same value for different objects

Tags: java, hashcode

i have an employee2 java file and i have created 3 objects , and i am trying to calculate the hashcode() of these objects using **System.identityhashCode(Object o)** , but it is always giving same value for all the objects , how is that possible

NOTE --> i have NOT implemented hashcode() or equals , i am just using default implementation of hashcode()

Code is as follows :

```
  public class employee2
  {
   private int empid;
   private String name;
   private String dept;

   employee2(){ 

   }

  public employee2(int empid,String name,String dept){
   this.empid=empid;
   this.name=name;
   this.dept=dept;
   }

  public static void main(String args[]){
        employee2 e1=new employee2(9846,"Amol Sngh","Science");
        employee2 e2=new employee2(9844,"Amol Singh","Scienc");
        employee2 e3=new employee2(98446,"Amol Singh","Science");
        employee2 e4=new employee2(96,"Amol Sh","Sciece");

       System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(e1)+"  "+System.identityHashCode(e2)+" "+System.identityHashCode(e3)+"  "+System.identityHashCode(e4));

   }     
 }
```

it is always giving value **366712642** for every object

Comment: I have just ran your code, it returned 4 different values: `1922154895`, `883049899`, `2093176254`, `1854731462`.

Comment: Impossible to reproduce. You probably ran an old version of your code. Recompile and re-run.

Comment: what an old version do you mean?

Comment: i want to kill myself , ran another file in netbeans with a similar code , sorry

Answer (score -2):

That is what I would expect. It will always give you the hashCode for the parent Object, not the individual instances:

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073618/java-s-system-identityhashcode.html